# How I can to convert a developer console script to Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i want to create a simple Chrome extension that run this script only clicking a button, now i run it on Google Chrome Developer Console (CTRT+SHIFT+J):

```
var user = "XXXXXX"; 
var hash2 = "YYYYYY"; 

var HA2 = MD5("GET" + ":" + uri); 
document.getElementById("user").value = user; 
document.getElementById("hidepw").value = MD5(hash2 + ":" + nonce +":" + "00000001" + ":" + "xyz" + ":" + qop + ":" + HA2); 
document.authform.submit();
```

I use this on Technicolor/Thomson/Mediacces router login page to log as user "XXXXXX" using hash2 instead of password.

I have read around to find a way to create a simple Chrome extension to add a button that execute this by clicking a button, but all tentatives fail.

I don't need to ask user to put user or hash, is the same for all users that will use this.

Comment: What approach did you try to achieve this. Seems like can be done using content scripts even without a button, just fire this script on document load event. Or you can display a button as a notification, and when the button is pressed just pass a message to content script to execute this script on your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by use of **Content scripts**. But content scripts run just as the page is loaded, so create a button through content script and add your JS code to the **onclick** event of the button.

Please comment below if some more specific details are needed.

Comment: My aim to turn that control into a button, transforming into a Chrome extension is due to the fact that I want to pass it to others without allowing them to see how it bypasses a given user login.
So that I can create an extension package, with inside the user and the hash2.
In short, a button that a normal user can use without problems.

Comment: _"I want to pass it to others without allowing them to see how it bypasses a given user login"_ How does an extension solve this? Chrome extensions are perfectly inspectable.

Comment: @sala_test I am sorry, but I am still unable to understand what exactly do you want to do with your chrome extension. Can you please elaborate your question?